# Cast from IEnumerable<object> to IEnumerable<decimal>

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have this code:

```
IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>> setValues = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>()
{
   { "IN_PARTENER", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["IN_PARTENER"]) }, 
   { "IN_DATA", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["IN_DATA"]) }, 
   { "IN_VALOARE", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["IN_VALOARE"]) }, 
   { "OUT_PARTENER", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["OUT_PARTENER"]) }, 
   { "OUT_DATA", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["OUT_DATA"]) }, 
   { "OUT_VALOARE", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["OUT_VALOARE"]) },
   { "TOTAL_ZI", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["TOTAL_ZI"]) },
};
```

I want to convert for the string `IN_VALOARE` and `OUT_VALOARE` from `string` to `decimal` but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 4):

You can do this inside the `Select`:

```
.Select(row => (decimal)row["IN_VALOARE"])
```

Full code:

```
IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>> setValues = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>()
{
   { "IN_PARTENER", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["IN_PARTENER"]) }, 
   { "IN_DATA", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["IN_DATA"]) }, 
   { "IN_VALOARE", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => (decimal)row["IN_VALOARE"]) }, 
   { "OUT_PARTENER", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["OUT_PARTENER"]) }, 
   { "OUT_DATA", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["OUT_DATA"]) }, 
   { "OUT_VALOARE", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => (decimal)row["OUT_VALOARE"]) },
   { "TOTAL_ZI", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["TOTAL_ZI"]) },
};
```

Since you cannot make a dictionary with different value types (without getting hacky), perhaps you should look at using a custom class instead:

```
public class MyThing
{
    public string InPartener { get; set; }
    public string InData { get; set; }
    public decimal InValoare { get; set; }
    public string OutPartener { get; set; }
    public string OutData { get; set; }
    public decimal OutValoare { get; set; }
    public string TotalZi { get; set; }
}
```

And make a list of those classes:

```
var myThings = dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => new MyThing
{
    InPartener = r["IN_PARTENER"],
    InData = r["IN_DATA"],
    InValoare = (decimal)r["IN_VALOARE"],
    OutPartener = r["OUT_PARTENER"],
    OutData = r["OUT_DATA"],
    OutValoare = (decimal)r["OUT_VALOARE"],
    TotalZi = r["TOTAL_ZI"]
};
```

Comment: i tried but i got this error: cannot convert from IEnumerable<decimal> to IEnumerable<object>

Comment: Well you are trying to store it in an incompatible dictionary now, but that's a different question.

Comment: I have no idea because I don't know your use case, but I'll show you a potentially better solution that doesn't use a dictionary.

Comment: ii neet to put this in IDictionary cause i have functions with this type of parameter

Comment: Well those functions won't work anyway with the conversion to decimal. My advice is to fix your code now rather than leaving it for the future when it will cost a lot more to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `decimal.Parse` inside the select for `IN_VALOARE` section

```
 { "IN_VALOARE", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => decimal.Parse(row["IN_VALOARE"].ToString())) },
```

which gives

```
 IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>> setValues = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>()
        {
           { "IN_PARTENER", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["IN_PARTENER"]) }, 
           { "IN_DATA", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["IN_DATA"]) }, 
           { "IN_VALOARE", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => decimal.Parse(row["IN_VALOARE"].ToString())) }, 
           { "OUT_PARTENER", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["OUT_PARTENER"]) }, 
           { "OUT_DATA", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["OUT_DATA"]) }, 
           { "OUT_VALOARE", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["OUT_VALOARE"]) },
           { "TOTAL_ZI", dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["TOTAL_ZI"]) },
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if need `IEnumerable<object>` then you actually don't need to cast field value to decimal or another type.

Second, if you need to get all columns in your dictionary, then all your code can be simplified to:

```
var setValues = dtResult.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
       .ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, 
                     c => dtResult.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<object>(c)));
```

Simple as that - get all columns and then create dictionary with column name as key and collection of column values as value.

---

NOTE: That depends on your needs, but consider also to work with strongly-typed entities instead of dictionaries, strings and objects. I.e. define entity

```
public class Transaction // chose good name here
{
    public string InPartener { get; set; }
    public string InData { get; set; }
    public decimal InValoare { get; set; }
    public string OutParener { get; set; }
    public string OutData { get; set; }
    public decimal OutValoare { get; set; } 
    public string TotalZi { get; set; }
}
```

The use LINQ to DataSet for converting your DataTable into collection of strongly typed objects:

```
 var transactions = from r in dtResult.AsEnumerable()
                    select new Transaction {
                       InPartener = r.Field<string>("IN_PARTENER"),
                       InData = r.Field<string>("IN_DATA"),
                       InValoare = r.Field<decimal>("IN_VALOARE"),
                       OutPartener = r.Field<string>("OUT_PARTENER"),
                       OutData = r.Field<string>("OUT_DATA"),
                       OutValoare = r.Field<decimal>("OUT_VALOARE"),
                       TotalZi = r.Field<string>("TOTAL_ZI")
                    };
```

That will give you nice strongly-typed business model with inteli sense support. E.g. if you need to calculate total InValoare:

```
  decimal total = transactions.Sum(t => t.InValoare);
```